# How can I send custom payload paramter with the NotificationPusher component to apple devices?

Tags: php, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am struggling with the usage of the [NotificationPusher](https://github.com/Ph3nol/NotificationPusher) component and the possibility to send custom parameters within the payload to apple products.

I've tried the following, since I've found this annotation within the docs on github.

```
$message = new Message("Hello there", [
    'message' => [
        'sound' => 'default'
    ],
    'custom' => [
        'lat' => 123,
        'lon' => 321,
        'radius' => 32,
        'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'action' => 'update'
    ]
]);
```

This syntax sadly didn't led to the expected result. The apple devices wouldn't receive these parameters.

I've also tried this, but this also failed.

```
$message = new Message("Hello there", [
    'message' => [
        'sound' => 'default',
        'custom_lat' => 123,
        'custom_lon' => 321,
        'custom_radius' => 32,
        'custom_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'custom_action' => 'update'
    ]
]);
```

What is the exact syntax so send custom parameters within the payload to apple devices with a push message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dug trough the source code on github and have found out, that the 'custom' key of the array wasn't extracted by the ASPN Adapter.

But I've found a piece of code that extracted the complete 'message' array, so my guess was to add the 'custom' array within the 'message' part, what then also was the solution for my problem.

```
$message = new Message("Hello there", [
    'message' => [
        'sound' => 'default',
        'custom' => [
            'lat' => 123,
            'lon' => 321,
            'radius' => 32,
            'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'action' => 'update'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same need. Started debugging and found that KhorneHoly is right: You need to send the payload under `custom` key. The array format is a little bit different, though:

```
$message = new Message('This is the message', [
    'custom'=> [
        'payloadKey' => 'payloadContent'
    ]
]);
```

I'm using `"sly/notification-pusher": "^2.3"`

Hope it helps =)